# cannot extract ID correctly from URL using split operation

Tags: python

I was using the standard split operation in python to extract ids from urls. It works for
urls of the form  `https://music.com/146` where I need to extract 146 but fails in these cases

```
https://music.com/144?i=150
```

from where I need to extract `150` after `i`
I use the standard

```
url.split("/")[-1]
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Use urllib to parse URLs.

Comment: After you split on `/`, you need to split the last field on `?` to get the parameters. Then you need to split the query parameters on `&` to get a list of parameters, and split each parameter on `=` to get the name and value. Finally you can search for the one with name == 'id' and get its corresponding value.

Comment: for `https://music.com/144?i=150` do you need the `144` or the `150` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Barmar mentioned, you can fix your code to:

```
url.split("/")[-1].split("?i=")[-1]
```

Basically you need to split `https://music.com/144?i=150` into `https://music.com` and `144?i=150`, get the second element `144?i=150`, then split it to `144` and `150`, then get the second.

If you need it to be number, you can use `int(url.split("/")[-1].split("?i="))[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

Python provides a few tools to make this process easier.

As @Barmar mentioned, you can use `urlsplit` to split the URL, which gets you a named tuple:

```
>>> from urllib import parse as urlparse
>>> x = urlparse.urlsplit('https://music.com/144?i=150')
>>> x
SplitResult(scheme='https', netloc='music.com', path='/144', query='i=150', fragment='')
```

You can use the `parse_qs` function to convert the query string into a dictionary:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(x.query)
{'i': ['150']}
```

Or in a single line:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit('https://music.com/144?i=150').query)['i']
['150']
```

Answer (score 1):

A particularly useful tool for manipulating URLs in Python is [`furl`](https://pypi.org/project/furl/), which provides an interface mimicking the [convenience](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) of Python's standard [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

Accessing a parameter in the query string (the part after the `?` of the URL) is as simple as indexing the URL's `args` attribute with the name of the parameter you want:

```
>>> from furl import furl
>>> url = furl('https://music.com/144?i=150')
>>> url.args['i']
'150'
```

In my opinion, this is a lot easier than using `urllib`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regexp

```
import re
url = 'https://music.com/144?i=150'
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\?', url)
if match:
   value = match[1] # 144
```

if you need the `150`

```
match = re.search(r'i=(\d+)', url)
if match:
   value = match[1] # 150
```